# Help to prove: $1-\tan^2(A) = \cos(2A)\sec^2(A)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to prove this identity and I keep getting stuck because I don’t know which side to work with and how to continue.
I rewrote $\tan^2 = \sin^2/\cos^2$ but then from there I got stuck.
Any hint? Thank you!

Comment: Please rewrite it better, for example: there is no argument to $\sec^2$

Comment: Do you mean $1 + \tan^2 A  = \sec^2 A$?

Comment: But @measure me this is what is written sec means 1/cos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 - \tan^2(A) = 1 - \dfrac{\sin^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)} = \dfrac{\cos^2(A) - \sin^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)}$$

Now we use the trigonometric identity: $$\cos^2(A) - \sin^2(A) = \cos(2A)$$ to get

$$\dfrac{\cos(2A)}{\cos^2(A)}$$

But this is nothing but
$$\cos(2A)\sec^2(A)$$

Because of the definition of the secant: $$\sec(A) = \dfrac{1}{\cos(A)}$$

Comment: How did you change it to cos^2-sin^2/cos^2?

Comment: Write $1$ as $\frac{\cos^2 A}{\cos^2 A}$. Then you can bring everything under a common denominator.

Comment: @toby mark is this a rule ? I have never heard of this before. Thank you!

Comment: It's not anything special. It's like how you would calculate $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{6} - \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Yessss I get it thank youuu very much I appreciate it!!!